# trigger for audit trail table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-trigger, audit-trail

Im trying to create an audit trail for my "exam" table that shows any changes that are made to the grade on the table.

So i am stuck on creating the trigger that shows the username and date that changes the current grade.

I have been looking around but cant find anything. Any help will be really appreciated.

The original table:

```
      CREATE TABLE exam (
      student_no INT NOT NULL,
      exam_code CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
      grade TINYINT NULL,
      FOREIGN KEY (student_no) REFERENCES student (student_no),
      FOREIGN KEY (exam_code) REFERENCES course (exam_code));
```

Audit table i created:

```
      CREATE TABLE Audit (
      student_no INT NOT NULL,
      exam_code CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
      old_grade TINYINT NULL,
      updated_grade TINYINT NULL,
      Current_username VARCHAR(30),
      Date_updated DATETIME
      );


      CREATE TRIGGER audit_trail
      ??????
```

Answer (score 0):

Below trigger can be an option.

```
CREATE TRIGGER audit_trail
AFTER UPDATE ON exam
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO Audit values(OLD.student_no,OLD.exam_code,OLD.grade,NEW.grade,CURRENT_USER(), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);  
END;
```

After any update in `exam` table, the above trigger will insert all associated information to `Audit` table.

You can check the demo **[here](http://rextester.com/OQZTJ88884)**